# Why does jquery behave like this

Tags: jquery

```
$('.box').click(function(){
    $(this).find('p').toggle(
        function () {
            $(this).css({"color" : "red"});
        },
        function () {
            $(this).css({"color" : "black"});
        }
    );
});
```

if i execute this script the 'p' color will change if i click on the 'p' not on the .box class why ? And how to i make it so that 'p' color changes when i click on the .box div

Comment: Could you clean that code up so it's legible? It's all over the place. (Edit: Never mind, John Hartsock did it for you. But please read the editing help: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: is your P inside the .box div, if yes that can be because of event propogation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) assigns event handlers to the `click` event, what you want is this:

```
$('.box').toggle(function(){
    $('p', this).css({"color" : "red"});
},  function () {
    $('p', this).css({"color" : "black"});
});
```

Every time you wrap a new function, `this` refers to the element you're dealing with (at least, for *this* example, [see more about how closures work here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-does-a-javascript-closure-work)), so at first it's the `.box` selector match, then it's each `p` inside, you want to assign a click toggle on `.box` to switch `p`'s color, so you use a [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) on `.box` directly.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to simply assign the colors in classes, and use [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass).

Give the `p` elements the `black` class initially, then toggle the `red` class.

CSS

```
    .black { color: black; }
    .red { color: red; }
```

jQuery

```
$('.box').click(function(){
        $(this).find('p').toggleClass('red');
});
```